# Do the simulated iOS devices have the same security ciphers available on the real devices?

Tags: ios, xcode, security, encryption, ios-simulator

Do the simulated iOS devices have the same security ciphers available on the real devices?

e.g. If I run an iPhone 4s in the Xcode simulator, will it have available to it the exact same list of ciphers as it would on a real 4s for the same iOS version?
If not, what's used for the simulated devices?

Comment: What is your specific concern? Why do you think there is a difference? Is there a specific cipher you have concerns about? AFAIK both have the same Common Crypto and it seems that applies to all the encryption.

I see no reason not to support the same encryption libraries in the Simulator as on the device.

Comment: I'm wondering if I can save some time for testing changes.  In this case, we made a change to the supported security in our API used by an iOS app, so I'm wondering how extensively I need to test in real devices.

Comment: I have never seen a difference between the simulator and the device in the encryption. What algorithms are you running? I have not used asymmetric (RSA) encryption. If the algorithms exist on both they will work on both. Are you using Common Crypto or something else?